# Android getting phone while playing video using videoview

Tags: android

I am using videoview control to play the mp4 video.

while playing the video if i get an phone call the video playing from the beginning.

how do i seek the position of the video to exist position before getting the call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the activity where you are playing video, you need to Override OnPause method of the Activity and in that you need to Seek the position and if required save it in preference.

Comment: I was working for Motorola bangalore for 2 year. not updated :)